# Is it ok to call the method again from inside the method?

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

Is this ok, I feel like its not right, like im doing a "GOTO", is this ok?

```
private void myCopySpecial()
{
    TSMUI.Picker myPicker1 = new TSMUI.Picker();
    Component c1 = myPicker1.PickObject(TSMUI.Picker.PickObjectEnum.PICK_ONE_OBJECT) as Component;

    TSMUI.Picker myPicker2 = new TSMUI.Picker();
    Beam fromBeam = myPicker2.PickObject(TSMUI.Picker.PickObjectEnum.PICK_ONE_PART) as Beam;

    if (c1 == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("That's not a component? Try again.");
        //User selected something other than a component, start again.
        myCopySpecial();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want a StackOverflowException? Because that's how you get a StackOverflowException.

Comment: It is fine. It is called recursion. Just make sure that at some point c1 will be different than `null` otherwise you will get a `StackOverlowException`

Comment: Ok thanks - the user is selecting c1 not the code so should be ok.

Comment: also, be aware the second time your function returns it will be into the same function, so any code after your recursion call will potentially execute again.

Comment: is your function waiting the user to enter some data and your method validating the user entered data? if so , yes you can.

Comment: The method does too much and you're mixing things. Why should all the work done if only `c1` is `null`. You could use a `while(c1 == null){c1 = pickC1...}`-loop

Comment: @HadiHassan Yes thats what happens, the user clicks an object on screen.

Comment: so yes you can do this, but make sure that there is a special click or some validation to exit from this method or it will stay for ever and maybe it will generate error for memory issues or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would take a very persistent user to let this method throw a StackOverflowException, but the possibility is there. That's because this design introduces a type of recursion that you, as a programmer, don't have control over.

A simple while loop will suffice:

```
private void PickComponent()
{
    Component c1 = null;

    while (c1 == null)
    {
        TSMUI.Picker myPicker1 = new TSMUI.Picker();
        c1 = myPicker1.PickObject(TSMUI.Picker.PickObjectEnum.PICK_ONE_OBJECT) as Component;

        if (c1 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a component.");
        }
    }
}
```

Or refactor it altogether into a method that actually picks the component and keeps prompting the user if they don't pick a component:

```
private Component PickObjectAsComponent()
{
    Component pickedComponent;

    do
    {
        TSMUI.Picker myPicker1 = new TSMUI.Picker();
        pickedComponent = myPicker1.PickObject(TSMUI.Picker.PickObjectEnum.PICK_ONE_OBJECT) as Component;

        if (pickedComponent == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a component.");
        }

    } (while pickedComponent == null)

    return pickedComponent;
}
```

Then from your code, you can simply call this method:

```
Component pickedComponent = PickObjectAsComponent();
```

I don't know how `TSMUI.Picker.PickObject()` can let the user cancel picking a part, because now this method won't exit until the user does pick one. I can imagine that they will regret starting this action in a workspace that doesn't contain any components.

Comment: i think do... while is better approach?

Comment: Won't it keep prompting the `MessageBox` to user and user won't even be able to pick the object?

Comment: @Shaharyar based on the one who asked the question, PickObject is waiting the user to pick an object

Comment: Thanks for your help, this while c1 is not a good option for me as if the user changes thier mind I dont seem to be able to get out of the loop - but thanks I learnt something.

Comment: @user3265525 you can't get out of your recursion as shown in the OP either.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that while testing! The user has the option to interrupt any command in the workspace and my try catch handles this. So I have gone with your solution to avoid recursion.

Comment: I have an Error in that method. It says not all code paths return a value? Is it because it thinks it can loop forever if a component is not picked?

Comment: @user3265525 there are two methods in my answer. I guess you meant the second one, which has now been fixed.

Comment: Sorry the second one! :)